# Why there are pass keywords in functions of Libraries like PyQt5 or Tkinter in Python

Tags: python

This is a really unnecessary thing to ask but I am curious about it so I was exploring thorough the scripts of Python Libraries like PyQt5, Tkinter etc. and saw "Pass" keywords in every class functions, why is there no real code and there are only 'pass' keywords.

for example look at this piece of code extracted from PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton:

```
class QPushButton(QAbstractButton):
    """
    QPushButton(parent: QWidget = None)
    QPushButton(str, parent: QWidget = None)
    QPushButton(QIcon, str, parent: QWidget = None)
    """
    def actionEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def autoDefault(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ autoDefault(self) -> bool """
        return False

    def changeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def checkStateSet(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def childEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def connectNotify(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def contextMenuEvent(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass
```

Comment: Presumably this is intended to be an abstract base class designed to be inherited from. The classes that inherit from it will implement the functionality. Note the "abstract" in "QAbstractButton"

Comment: Had the modules been written prior to Python 2.6, they probably would have used the `abc` module. It may never have been worth the effort to update to using it once it was available.

Comment: @JohnColeman but why are there pass keywords

Comment: @DaPythonprogrammer  Because the syntax of a function `def` requires a body. This is a way to have a body which doesn't actually do anything. The point is to stipulate what functions an inhering class needs to implement, not to actually implement them.